# Is there any server virtualization software supports subdomains?

Tags: vps, xen, kvm-virtualization, openvz

I installed openvz in my server but to create more virtual machines I need more than one ip address. But my service provider can only give one ip address for my server. Is there any software that supports subdomain or Server Name Indication. I searched google to find out whether Xen or KVM supports subdomain, but I failed to find any result.

Comment: Lack of IP addresses isn't a problem you'll solve with virtualization. What _exactly_ are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to create virtual machines for my colleagues. We have different projects working on for finals, some use JVM and others use python, I installed openvz with ISPConfig to manage the server, but I can't create virtual machines. do you have any ideas?

Comment: Every virtual machine has to have its own IP address (just like every physical machine). Consider using IPv6 if you can.

Comment: Michael Hampton's comment is the best one so far - if you can use IPv6 you won't need NAT and port forwarding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds to me like you need a private cloud, that anyone can spin up VMs with worry about additional config, ie networks / source nats to the internet etc. you could try cloudstack from citrix. That will do what you want.. http://incubator.apache.org/cloudstack/

Comment: Thanks! I will check it out. I am reading their documentation and really like this private cloud concept.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is to set up a private network with its own netspace, behind a router/server that does NAT. You give the various servers ipaddresses within the networks assigned to this, e.g. 10.0.0.1 and so on. Then have the router/NAT server do portmapping so that when colleague A connects by ssh to port 2022, they will arrive at virtual server A. When colleague B connects by ssh to port 2122, they will arrive at virtual server B, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a virtual local network for your VMs and set up NAT using your external IP.
[HOWTO](http://openvz.org/Using_NAT_for_container_with_private_IPs)

In general you need to create a bridge on your host node using bridge-utils and assign some local IP to it.
Then add a network interface with another local IP to the container and set it to use your new bridge.
There is another [HOWTO](http://wiki.openvz.org/VEs_and_HNs_in_different_subnets) for that on the OpenVZ wiki.
After that all you have to do is configure NAT on your host node using iptables.

Comment: Can you provide more details in your answer than just a link? SF policy is that answers should be able to stand on their own in the event that the site the link goes to goes away. A high level of the steps involved would suffice.